# What is the domain of this function in calculus?

Tags: calculus

**Given this function find the domain of it:**

$\sqrt{1-2^t}$

Now, just by looking at this anyone can tell that the domain is t>=0, but like all calculus students, we must show the work. I have this so far, but I am stuck as to how to get to the final last steps of isolating 't'.

**My work so far:**

$\sqrt{1-2^t}$

$$=1-2^t$$

$$1\geq2^t$$

$$\ln1 \geq \ln2^t$$

$$0 \geq t(\ln2)$$

I am stuck now, how do I get rid of the $\ln2$ so that only this is left:

$$ 0\geq t$$

Help is much needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide both sides by the constant factor ($ln(2)$) silly!

Comment: silliness isn't appreciated

Comment: Right, 0/ln2 = 0 and so forth. I didn't consider dividing it, I guess I was over thinking the last step.

Comment: @user3718584 it does require $\ln 2 > 0$, mind

Comment: @John Fernley Well to prove that just exponent $e$ by both sides to get $e^{ln(2)}>e^0$ which holds true since $2>1$

Comment: why does it require ln 2 >0

Comment: Dividing or multiplying a inequality by a negative number reverses the inequality. E.g. $6>4$ if we divide by $-2$ we get $-3<-2$ the inequality sign "flipped"

Comment: How would we know if that was a good or bad thing if by first glance we didn't know that t<=0? I mean, this makes perfect sense since I already knew what the domain was, but if it's some super complex function on a test where no calculators are aloud how do I know?

Comment: @user3718584 I'm not saying you should know whether it's the right answer, I'm just saying $$-t > 0 \implies t < 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$ln(2)$ is not zero, just divide both sides and there you go.